# Node.js listen for module load

Tags: javascript, node.js

With RequireJS on the front-end, we can listen to see when modules get loaded into the runtime module cache using:

```
requirejs.onResourceLoad = function (context, map, depArray) {
    console.log('onResourceLoad>>>', 'map.id:', map.id, 'context:', context);
};
```

Can we do this with Node.js somehow? Will be useful for debugging. Especially when servers are loading different files (or in different order) based on configuration.

I assume this might be documented in

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

but I am not seeing anything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/4d6297fef05267e82dd653f7ad99c95f9a5e2cef/lib/module.js) for `require()`, you will find this:

```
Module._load = function(request, parent, isMain) {
    if (parent) {
        debug('Module._load REQUEST %s parent: %s', request, parent.id);
    }
```

This shows that you can leverage the `debug()` call to get the information you need. In order to do this, you will notice that module is setup using `util.debuglog('module')`. This means that you need to run your application with with the `NODE_DEBUG` variable set to `module`. You can do it the following way from the console:

```
NODE_DEBUG=module node main.js
```

This will log what you are looking for.

Comment: I'll be damned, nice work, although all we will get is logging info, can't do anything with it

Comment: I second that :-)

Comment: @AlexanderMills Curiously what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Well for one, I might want to log it to a separate file, using streams..Otherwise it will just get jumbled about in stdout.

Comment: Monkey patch for the win!

Comment: that would be interesting haha

Comment: it would also be useful to filter the debug log so that you only log modules in your project...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a documented callback API for the purpose of module load callbacks ([although a logging mechanism for module loading appears to exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40053734/504931)).

Here's a quick workaround to the apparent lack of such a callback, by monkeypatching [`Module._load`](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/):

```
const Module = require('module');
const originalModuleLoad = Module._load;
Module._load = function() {
    originalModuleLoad.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log("Loaded with arguments " + JSON.stringify(arguments));
}
```

I executed the above code in a REPL and then did `require('assert')`. Lo and behold:

```
> require('assert')
Loading with arguments {"0":"assert","1":{"id":"<repl>","exports":{},"filename":null,"loaded":false,"children":[],"paths":["/Users/mz2/Projects/manuscripts-endnote-promo/repl/node_modules","/Users/mz2/Projects/manuscripts-endnote-promo/node_modules","/Users/mz2/Projects/node_modules","/Users/mz2/node_modules","/Users/node_modules","/Users/mz2/.nvm-fish/v6.1.0/lib/node_modules","/Users/mz2/.node_modules","/Users/mz2/.node_libraries","/Users/mz2/.nvm-fish/v6.1.0/lib/node"]},"2":false}
```

Please don't think about using code like above for anything but debug only purposes.

Comment: The principle still works, but: you need to return the value returned by `originalModuleLoad.apply(...)`, and I found that `arguments` contained circular references that `JSON.stringify()` couldn't handle (but I only wanted `arguments[0]`, so just printed that.)

Answer (score 1):

Because node.js modules are imported (required) *synchronously*, simply having the require statement means the module is imported.

While RequireJS can import modules asynchronously, the even listening is an important feature, but native require in Node.js leaves this necessity out. This way, as you probably know:

```
const module = require('module')
// You can use the module here, async or sync.
```

To add to that, not only require is sync, but also in order to use a module it has to be explicitly required in the same file where it's used. This can be bypassed in several ways, but best practice is to require in every module where you use a module.

For specific modules which require async initialization, either the module should provide an event, or you can wrap the init function using a promise or a callback. For example, using a promise:

```
const module = require('module')
// Create a promise to initialize the module inside it:
const initialized = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Init module inside the promise:
    module.init((error) => {
        if(error){
            return reject(error)
        }
        // Resolve will indicate successful init:
        resolve()
    })
})

// Now with wrapped init, proceed when done:
initialized
    .then(() => {
        // Module is initialized, do what you need.
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle init error.
    })
```

Comment: I feel this is beside the point of the question – regardless of whether module loading is synchronous or asynchronous, you may want to observe module loading from some other context than where you loaded it. For example you may want to observe module loading from the entry point to your program, right from its startup, e.g. to see the order / set of modules that are being loaded. Even if the loading itself is synchronous and requires explicit, module loading can (and does often) happen on different event loop cycles in a more complex Node program, and there is a runtime module cache involved.